# docker-compose build context dockerfile envar image

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I would like use `docker-compose` to build/run dockerfiles that have envars in their `FROM` keyword. The problem that I am getting now is that I seem to be unable to pass envars from my environment through docker-compose into the dockerfile.

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  api:
    build: 'api/'
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./api/php/:/var/www/html/
```

### Dockerfile in 'api/'

```
FROM ${DOCKER_IMAGE_API}
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

### Why?

I want to do this so that I can run docker-compose from a bash script that detects the host architecture and changes the base image of the underlying dockerfiles in the host application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FROM` instructions support variables that are declared by any `ARG` instructions that occur before the first `FROM`. So what you can do is this:

```
ARG IMAGE
FROM $IMAGE
```

when you run the build command, you then pass the --build-arg as follows:

```
 docker build -t test --build-arg IMAGE=alpine .
```

you can also choose to have a default value for the `IMAGE` variable, to be used if the --build-arg flag isn't used.

Alternatively, in case you were to use docker compose build and not docker build (and I think this is your case), you can specify the variable in the docker-compose build --build-arg:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  api:
    build: .
```

and then

```
docker compose build --build-arg IMAGE=alpine
```